# Is there any way to define testdata specific to the environments

Tags: jmeter, test-data

Besides using the CSV config file and beanshell programming, is there any way to define the testdata  specific to the environments?

Each environment varies different testdata(values) using same jmx script.

For example :Firstname,LastName,ProjectName so on..

Answer (score 1):

You can have different properties in different environment.

You can have different or additional properties file

> -p, --propfile 
>         the jmeter property file to use
>
> -q, --addprop 
>         additional JMeter property file(s)

or override each property per environment using [command line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

> -J[prop_name]=[value]
>   defines a local JMeter property.

Comment: Could you please elaborate by using above columns FirstName,LastName,Project.I am not sure how define those in property file as each clouds will have thousands of data values.Let’s say FirstName as  values like Tom,Daniel,Peter so on..

Comment: you can have different CSV file per environment and have the CSV file be the different property value, for production e.g. -JcsvFile=prodData.csv, for QA -JcsvFile=qaData.csv

Comment: The entire test has 9 scenarios and each scenario uses different csv file.Lets say i can define property as -JcsvFile=PerfCreateNewEmployee.csv for One scenario,in this way how do I define PerfScenario2.csv ...PerfScenario9 for the same test.

Comment: For 9 CSVs you need 9 sets you can use  
 -JcsvFile=PerfCreateNewEmployee, and then file names will be: ${csvFile}1.csv, ..${csvFile}9.csv

Comment: So it will be -JcsvFile=PerfCreateNewEmployee.csv,PerfNewProjectSetup.csv,PerfPensionReport.csv so..on.Am I correct?

Comment: Won't it be easier with the scenario numbers from your last comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158450/discussion-between-rpagadala-and-user7294900).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) like:

1. In .jmx script define `Firstname` using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like

   ```
   ${__P(Firstname)}
   ```
2. When you start JMeter pass this `Firstname` property value via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -JFirstname=John
   ```

See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) User Manual chapter for more details.